# Add character to column based on ascending order of another column if condition met pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Stuck on a data problem in pandas. See data below:

```
| Product | Level | Cost |
 --------- ------- ------
| Prod_A  | L1    | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L1    | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L1    | 200  |
| Prod_A  | L2    | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L3    | 100  |
| Prod_B  | L1    | 150  |
| Prod_B  | L1    | 150  |
| Prod_B  | L2    | 200  |
| Prod_B  | L2    | 300  |
| Prod_C  | L3    | 100  |
```

The rules are:

1. Only one Cost for each unique (Product, Level) combination.
2. If multiple Cost for each unique (Product, Level) combination, add a letter to the Level value (L1 A, L1 B, etc) based on the Cost value (L1 A being the smallest Cost).
3. If (Product, Level) combination has a unique Cost then do nothing.

Desired output:

```
| Product | Level | Cost |
 --------- ------- ------
| Prod_A  | L1 A  | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L1 A  | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L1 B  | 200  |
| Prod_A  | L2    | 100  |
| Prod_A  | L3    | 100  |
| Prod_B  | L1    | 150  |
| Prod_B  | L1    | 150  |
| Prod_B  | L2 A  | 200  |
| Prod_B  | L2 B  | 300  |
| Prod_C  | L3    | 100  |
```

Comment: should the desired output of `Level` for `Prod_A` be `L1 A`, `L1 B` when cost is `100`. For `Prod_A` and cost `200`, i think `Level` should stay as `L1` based on your note. Did I get it right? Similarly, for `Prod_B`, we have two `L1` for cost of `150` so shouldnt this also end up with `A` and `B` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz so since ```Prod_B```, ```L1``` has only one cost of ```150``` then we can ignore. But since ```Prod_B``` and ```L2``` and 2 different Cost (```200```, ```300```) we need to add a letter to the ```L2```. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
charlist='ABCDEFG'
dd = {k:' '+v for k, v in enumerate(charlist)}
df['Level'] += df.groupby(['Product', 'Level'])['Cost']\
                 .transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0] if x.nunique()>1 else -1)\
                 .map(dd).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
  Product Level  Cost
0  Prod_A  L1 A   100
1  Prod_A  L1 A   100
2  Prod_A  L1 B   200
3  Prod_A    L2   100
4  Prod_A    L3   100
5  Prod_B    L1   150
6  Prod_B    L1   150
7  Prod_B  L2 A   200
8  Prod_B  L2 B   300
9  Prod_C    L3   100
```

***Details:***

First, create dictionary of the characters to append.

Then `groupby` product and level using `transform` unique "encode" each Cost with `pd.Series.factorize` if there is only one Cost amount then use -1.

Lastly, map the results of the  "encoded" cost using the dictionary and fillna with a blank string.